# Map a column from df2 based on check whether string column value of df1 matches with any column(list type) of df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes A and B .I would like to create a new column 'suggested_Vendor' in dataframe B which consist of corresponding mapping from dataframe A based on certain checks:

1. Add the first 'suggested_Vendor' from dataframe A with any match between dataframe B fruit value and datframe A 'preferred_fruits' list type column.
2. If no matches present return 'suggested_Vendor' as 'None' in dataframe B output
3. If the vendor_capacity exceeds then match name for 2nd best preferred vendor in data frame A and so on.
4. There's no relation between Id ,userid in both data frames

Dataframe A

```
| Id | vendor_name| preferred_fruits          |vendor_capacity|
| ---| -----------| --------------------------|---------------|
| 1  | X          |['apple','orange','banana']|2              |
| 2  | Y          |['kiwi']                   |1              |
| 3  | Z          |['banana','orange']        |1              | 
| 4  | W          |['apple']                  |1              |
```

Dataframe B

```
| userid | fruit      |
| ---    | -----------|
| 1      | apple      |
| 2      | orange     |
| 3      | apple      | 
| 4      | banana     |
| 5      | kiwi       |
| 6      | strawberry |
```

Output Dataframe B

```
| userid | fruit      | suggested_Vendor|
| ---    | -----------|-----------------|
| 1      | apple      | X               |
| 2      | orange     | X               |
| 3      | apple      | W               |
| 4      | banana     | Z               |
| 5      | kiwi       | Y               | 
| 6      | strawberry | None            |
```

Any pythonic way for this. I would appreciate some explanation on the code.

Comment: you will get `X` at userid 4?

Comment: no the vendor capacity for X is 2 .That's why the second match is mapped here

Answer (score 1):

Please find the answer below, I have explained the steps in the comments.
I have modified in dfA to remove the rows with lists in the fruits column, such that dfA has multiple rows of same vendor but with different fruits (also a better database design).

```
import pandas as pd

# Create Dataframes
dfA = pd.DataFrame()
dfA["vendor_name"] = ["X","Y","Z","W"]
dfA["fruits"] = [['apple','orange','banana'],['kiwi'],['banana','orange'],['apple']]
dfA["cap"] = [2,1,1,1]

dfB = pd.DataFrame()
dfB["userid"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
dfB["fruit"] = ["apple","orange","apple","banana","kiwi","strawberry"]

"""
Add new rows in dfA, by splitting the "fruits" list
Now, each row in dfA will have a single fruit only
"""

l = len(dfA)
for index, row in dfA.iterrows():
    for fruit in row["fruits"]:
        newrow = pd.Series([row["vendor_name"],fruit, row["cap"]], index=["vendor_name","fruits","cap"])
        dfA = dfA.append(newrow, ignore_index=True)

# removing the earlier rows with list of fruits in each column
dfA = dfA[l:]

# Add current capacity column in dfA
dfA["curr_cap"] = dfA["cap"].copy()

# Add vendor column in dfB
dfB["vendor"] = ""

# Loop over dfB to select vendor
for index,row in dfB.iterrows():
    # get fruit
    fruit = row["fruit"]
    # get available vendors
    df = dfA[(dfA['fruits'] == fruit) & (dfA["curr_cap"] > 0)]
    # if vendors are available
    if len(df):
        if len(df) > 1:
            # if more than 1 vendor available, sort (descending) by current capacity
            df = df.sort_values(by = 'curr_cap', ascending=False)
        # get vendor name
        selected_vendor = df.iloc[0]["vendor_name"]
        # reduce capacity of the vendor in all rows where vendor exists
        dfA.loc[dfA['vendor_name'] == selected_vendor, 'curr_cap'] -= 1
        # set selected vendor in dfB
        dfB.at[index,"vendor"] = selected_vendor
    # if no vendors available
    else:
        dfB.at[index, "vendor"] = None


print(dfB)
```